# How to change css of first child based on second child?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a div which has 2 children

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child1"> XYZ </div>
    <span class="child2">67</span>
</div>
```

if the `child2` has text in it, I want `child1` to be of 10px width but if `child2` is an empty span, I want `child1` to take 100% width. I tried using `only-child` but it is not working as anyway span is a child whether its empty or not.

Answer (score -2):

use this

```
div.parent .child2 ~ .child1{width:10px};
div.parent .child2:empty ~ .child1{width:100%};
```

Comment: The element on the right side of the [general sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) (`~`) only matches those siblings that come *after* the element on the left side.